# How does foreach casts objects to specified types?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I have a question about `foreach` behavior in `C#`.

My custom class implements a custom `GetEnumerator`. This method returns another `object` that is implicitly convertible to `string`.

However if I do `foreach(string s in customClass)` it fails during run-time ("Unable to cast object of type .. to string").

However if I do `string x = new B()` it works like a charm.

NOTE: There is nothing in particular I need to achieve here, I just want to understand what is going on. I am particularly interested in this *non*-generic behavior.

Any ideas? What fundamental knowledge am I missing?

Code to replicate this:

```
public class A : IEnumerable
{
    #region IEnumerable Members

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new B();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class B
{
    public static implicit operator string( B b )
    {
        return "to-stringed implicit";
    }
}

// CODE:

A a = new A();

// Works.
B b = new B();
string xxx = b;

// Doesnt work.
foreach( string str in a )
{
}
```

Comment: Your implicit operator on`B` is the door to hell ;)

Comment: Section "The foreach statement" (8.8.4 of the C# 5.0 specification) - it covers exactly what is and is not performed in the foreach (as well as code it converted to). The document is generally in your "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\VC#\Specifications\YYYY" folder.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I ve though I made it clear enough that this code has nothing to do with practical use. I just wanted to know, why implicit/explicit cast is not called in foreach. Maybe someone could let me know how to write questions more clearly so that people stop pointing out these things.

Comment: Also see http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/#more-1315

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your implicit conversion can only be used if the compiler sees it can be used at compile-time:

```
B b = new B();
string str = b;
```

It can't be used at run-time:

```
B b = new B();
object obj = b;
string str = obj; // will fail at run-time
```

Basically, this is because it would be far too expensive to look through *all* the possible conversions from `obj` to a `string` that might work. (See [this Eric Lippert blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)).

---

Your `IEnumerator` returns objects, so calling `foreach (string str in a)` is trying to convert an `object` to a `B` at runtime.

```
var e = a.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();
object o = e.Current;
string str = o; // will fail at run-time
```

If you instead use `foreach(B item in a) { string str = item; ... }`, the runtime conversion is from `object` to `B` (which works, because each object *is* a `B`), and the conversion from `B` to `str` can be made by the *compiler*.

```
var e = a.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();
object o = e.Current;
B item = o;        // will work at run-time because o _is_ a B
string str = item; // conversion made by the compiler
```

---

A different way to fix this would be to make `A` implement `IEnumerable<B>` instead of just `IEnumerable`. Then, `foreach (string str in a)` translates more as

```
var e = a.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();
B b = e.Current; // not object!
string str = b;  // conversion made by the compiler
```

so the compiler can make the conversion without you having to change your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the only one that truly shows why is this happening.

Answer (score 5):

The foreach method doesn't require you to implement `IEnumerable`. All that's required is that your class has a method called `GetEnumerator`:

```
public class A
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new B();
    }
}
```

and then you could use it in a `foreach`:

```
A a = new A();
foreach (B str in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.GetType());
}
```

But the foreach statement will not call the implicit operator. You will have to do this manually:

```
foreach (B item in a)
{
    string str = item;
    // use the str variable here
}
```

Comment: This is the same *fix* I came up with when looking at this, and this may be a dumb question, but why doesn't it call the implicit operator?

Comment: Because that's how the designers of the C# language decided to implement it. I am not one of them so cannot give you the exact reason.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I tried to give reason why conversion does not happen based on C# spec... moving next step and explaining why particular set of rules was picked for the spec is where it gets "can't give exact reason" :)

Comment: Thank you. I am essentially asking for why is this happening, not for how to fix it (as you suggest to do manual convert). Good point about not having to implement IEnumerable though, I didnt know that. However it makes little difference i think as IEnumerable is only one method: GetEnumerator.

Answer (score 3):

Based on "foreach statement" section in the C# specification (8.8.4 of the C# 5.0 specification) I believe your case falls into section where "enumerated type have GetEnumerable which returns proper object" - there is no implicit conversion to determine type of element (there are some in case there is no unique GetEnumerable on the class)

> The collection type is X, the enumerator type is E, and the element type is the type of the Current property.

The `foreach` is translated in following code (removed try/finally) in your case:

```
// foreach( string str in items )
//    embedded-statement


IEnumerator enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
  {
    string str = (string)(Object)enumerator.Current; // **
    embedded-statement
  }
}
```

Note that on line `**` the type of object to be converted is `Object` (as it determined by result of `enumerator.Current` which is `Object` in case of non-generic `IEnumerator`. As you can see there is no mentioning of your `B` type that would allow your implicit conversion.

Note: Specification can be found in normal VS C# installation at following location:
"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\VC#\Specifications\YYYY" (XX is your version 10 for VS2010, 11 for VS2012 and YYYY is locale 1033 for EN-US).

Comment: Thank you. Somewhat more convoluted way of saying the same as Rawlings answer I belive.

Comment: @NeverStopLearning, Rawlings answer is definitely easier to read and correct... if you nick name is of any value I'd suggest to look at the specification itself to see explanation from the source (also covers how matching to non-interface version of GetEnumerator works).

Comment: Indeed, thats why I have upvoted your answer even before too. I will check the specification - I never knew such document existed.